# Json to Dataframe: error: error in 1:nrow(test) : argument of length 0

Tags: r, json, apply

I'm trying to convert my complicated JSON file with 150.000 observations to a dataframe. Someone generously helped me constructing the code, but I keep running into the same error: Error in 1:nrow(test) : argument of length 0. I've searched the topic on the community but none of the answers provided work in my case. Any tips are welcome!

These two lines give the error:

```
valid<-which(sapply(1:nrow(test),  function(j) {length(test[[1]][[j]])}) >0)
NullResponses<-which(sapply(1:nrow(test),  function(j) {length(test[[1]][[j]])}) == 0)
```

Structure of json:

[image]
This is the whole code:

```
#test<- result from converting the JSON response.  
#vector of reviewid, used to make the initial request to the API
reviewid<-c(98338143, 58929813, 65945346)

#find only the responses that are not Null or blank
valid<-which(sapply(1:nrow(test),  function(j) {length(test[[1]][[j]])}) >0)
NullResponses<-which(sapply(1:nrow(test),  function(j) {length(test[[1]][[j]])}) == 0)

#create a list of data frames with the data from row of the response
dflist<-lapply( valid, function(j) {
  temp<-t(as.matrix(unlist(test[j,])))
  df<-data.frame(reviewid=reviewid[j], temp, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  df
})

#bind the rows together.
answer<-bind_rows(dflist)
```

Json:

```
 [{},
    {"daily":
       [{"time":"2010-03-18",
       "summary":"Partly cloudy throughout the day.",
       "icon":"partly-cloudy-day",
       "sunriseTime":"2010-03-18 07:22:51",
       "sunsetTime":"2010-03-18 19:25:28",
       "moonPhase":0.08,
       "precipIntensity":0,
       "precipIntensityMax":0,
       "precipProbability":0,
       "temperatureHigh":63.14,  
       "temperatureHighTime":1268928000,
       "temperatureLow":45.16,
       "temperatureLowTime":1268971200,
       "apparentTemperatureHigh":63.14,
       "apparentTemperatureHighTime":1268928000,
       "apparentTemperatureLow":45.16,
       "apparentTemperatureLowTime":1268971200,
       "dewPoint":36.97,
       "humidity":0.58,
       "pressure":1025.96,
       "windSpeed":1.24,
       "windGust":7.87, 
       "windGustTime":1268866800,
       "windBearing":48,
       "cloudCover":0.54,
       "uvIndex":5,
       "uvIndexTime":1268913600,
       "visibility":6.19,
       "temperatureMin":43.97,
       "temperatureMinTime":"2010-03-18 07:00:00",
       "temperatureMax":63.14,
       "temperatureMaxTime":"2010-03-18 17:00:00",
       "apparentTemperatureMin":42.03,
       "apparentTemperatureMinTime":"2010-03-18 08:00:00",
       "apparentTemperatureMax":63.14,
       "apparentTemperatureMaxTime":"2010-03-18 17:00:00"}]},

    {"daily":
       [{"time":"2010-05-30 01:00:00",
       "summary":"Mostly cloudy until evening.",
       "icon":"partly-cloudy-day",
       "sunriseTime":"2010-05-30 05:38:39",
       "sunsetTime":"2010-05-30 22:44:55",
       "moonPhase":0.58,
       "precipIntensity":0.0038,
       "precipIntensityMax":0.0766,
       "precipIntensityMaxTime”:"2010-05-30 04:00:00",
       "precipProbability":1,
       "precipType":"rain", 
       "temperatureHigh":58.99,
       "temperatureHighTime":1275242400, 
       "temperatureLow":36.62,  
       "temperatureLowTime":1275278400, 
       "apparentTemperatureHigh":58.99, 
       "apparentTemperatureHighTime":1275242400, 
       "apparentTemperatureLow":36.62,
       "apparentTemperatureLowTime":1275278400,
       "dewPoint":43.61,
       "humidity":0.76,
       "pressure":1011.52,
       "windSpeed":4.65,
       "windGust":21.4,
       "windGustTime":1275224400,
       "windBearing":350,
       "cloudCover":0.61,
       "uvIndex":5,
       "uvIndexTime":1275213600,
       "visibility":5.85, 
       "temperatureMin":45.99,
       "temperatureMinTime":"2010-05-30 07:00:00",
       "temperatureMax":58.99,
       "temperatureMaxTime":"2010-05-30 20:00:00",
       "apparentTemperatureMin":43.31,
       "apparentTemperatureMinTime":"2010-05-30 06:00:00",
       "apparentTemperatureMax":58.99,
       "apparentTemperatureMaxTime":"2010-05-30 20:00:00"}]}]
```

Comment: This did not make a difference, but the problem has been solved, thank you for the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the converted json is a list of lists, which won't work with the `nrow()` funcition. Can you try this code instead and check if the result is what you expect?

```
valid         <- which(sapply(1:NROW(test),  function(j) {length(test[[j]])}) > 0)
NullResponses <- which(sapply(1:NROW(test),  function(j) {length(test[[j]])}) == 0)

dflist <- lapply(valid, function(j) {
  temp <- t(as.matrix(unlist(test[j])))
  df   <- data.frame(reviewid = reviewid[j], temp, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  df
})

answer <- bind_rows(dflist)
```